# Who’s house was Jesus at in Mark 2:1?

Tags: greek, jesus, mark

> “And when he returned to Capernaum after some days, it was reported that he was at home.”
> ‭‭Mark‬ ‭2:1‬ ‭

Mark expects the reader to know the house in question. How likely is it that it was his own house?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not told the answer to this question so we do not know.  The "home" in Mark 2:1 refers to Jesus' home town.

Note the helpful comments of Ellicott -

> (1) **And again he entered into Capernaum**.—See Notes on Matthew
> 9:1-8. St. Mark alone names Capernaum, St. Matthew describing it as
> “His own city.” The house may have been Peter’s, as before in Mark
> 1:29.

The Expositor's Commentary is similar:

> **the house** Either His own house, which He occupied with His mother and His brethren (Mark 3:21), or possibly that of St Peter.

Comment: The home refers to the house which would later have a hole made in its roof. And it went from a house he could go back to (whether his own or another’s) to no where to lay his head.